# digitally signing pdf embedded on web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a pdf document embedded on my razor page. I want the users to sign the document digitally. Normally, when I open the pdf document using adobe, I can see a menu bar saying "sign document by typing or drawing signature", something like this:
[image]

I am not seeing anything like this when I embedded the pdf document on my razor web page. below is my code, I used to embed the pdf document:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                string embed = "<object data=\"{0}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"1000px\" height=\"1000px\">";
                embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}\">here</a>";
                embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
                embed += "</object>";

                TempData["Embed"] = string.Format(embed, "/BlankPDFFiles/Test.pdf");
                return View();
            }
           
        }
```

This is an intranet application, Is their any way, I can have the employees sign the pdf document that is embedded on the web page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to save the signature as web image and then insert the signature to the pdf file. Something like this: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/signature/applicationscenarios/signingpdfdocuments/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Do you want to implement print functionality on button click here, I notice a question right?

Comment: yes, that's right